# Как вывести ошибку в случае некорректного ввода данных в форму

Tags: java, веб-сервер

Разрабатываю веб-проект(Java EE + HTML + CSS). Все кое-как работает, но есть косяки. Вопрос по одному из них. Есть у пользователя веб-приложения возможность регистрации. Он заходит на сайт, вводит данные и они заносятся в базу(MySQL).
Но, в случае некорректного ввода данных я хочу вывести ошибку. 
Как сделать обязательными для заполнения каждые поля?
Если отправить пустую форму выскочит 500 ошибка, а это ужас. 
Помогите пожалуйста. Времени совсем нет...
Код формы:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="ftm" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<ftm:setLocale value="${sessionScope.locale}"/>
<ftm:setBundle basename="messages" var="i18n"/>
<center><h5><ftm:message bundle="${i18n}" key="register.namePage"/></h5></center>
<div class="error">${errorMsg}</div>
<br/>
<form id="form_input" action="frontController?command=registration" method="post">
    <ftm:setLocale value="${sessionScope.locale}"/>
    <ftm:setBundle basename="messages" var="i18n"/>
    <ftm:message bundle="${i18n}" key="register.name"/><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" id="name"/><br/>
    <ftm:message bundle="${i18n}" key="register.email"/><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email"/><br/>
    <ftm:message bundle="${i18n}" key="register.password"/><br/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" id="password"/><br/>
    <ftm:message bundle="${i18n}" key="register.address"/><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="address" name="address" id="address"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" values="
    <p><ftm:message bundle="${i18n}" key="register.submit"/>"></p>
</form>
```

Код серверной части:

```
public class RegistrationUserController implements Controller {
    private UserService userService = UserServiceIplm.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void execute(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        String address = req.getParameter("address");
        if (email == null || password == null || name == null || address == null) {
            resp.setHeader("errorMsg", "Invalid data");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(MAIN_PAGE);
            dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
            return;
        }
        User user = new User(name, email, password, address);
        userService.save(user);

        if (user != null) {
            String contextPath = req.getContextPath();
            resp.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/frontController?command=email");
            return;
        } else {
            resp.setHeader("errorMsg", "Invalid");
            req.setAttribute("errorMsg", "Invalid");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(MAIN_PAGE);
            dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В `HTML 5` есть атрибут `required`

Comment: Курсы <epam>? )))

Comment: спасибо) да, только от ПВТ)

Comment: Что такое пвт???

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему через использование атрибута тега "required" на стороне клиента)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]